# ItemCount not updating

Tags: java, oop

this is my output:

**Item Code: 1**, Item Name: X Box Series X, Supplier: Microsoft, Department Laptops, Desktops & Consoles Cost: 449.99

**Item Code: 1,** Item Name: Playstation 5 , Supplier: Sony, Department Laptops, Desktops & Consoles Cost: 449.99

**Item Code: 1,** Item Name: Oculus Quest 2, Supplier: Facebook, Department Laptops, Desktops & Consoles Cost: 299.0

I don't understand why the Item Code does not update. What am i doing wrong?

```
public class OrderApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MAX = 5;
    int itemCount = 0;

    OrderItem[] stock = new OrderItem[MAX]; // Initialise empty array with MAx as the size limit

    stock = addThreeItems(stock, itemCount);
    itemCount += 3; // cannot return 2 variables within one method therefore itemCount must be
                    // increased outside of method

    testPrint(stock, itemCount); // Prints all current items
}

public static void testPrint(OrderItem[] stock, int itemCount) { // Prints all current items
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(stock[i].toString());
    }
}

public static OrderItem[] addThreeItems(OrderItem[] stock, int itemCount) { // Adds 3 predetermined items

    OrderItem itm1 = new OrderItem("X Box Series X", "Microsoft", 449.99, Department.COMPUTING);
    OrderItem itm2 = new OrderItem("Playstation 5 ", "Sony", 449.99, Department.COMPUTING);
    OrderItem itm3 = new OrderItem("Oculus Quest 2", "Facebook", 299.00, Department.COMPUTING);
    stock[itemCount++] = itm1; // ++ iterates AFTER being used making it useful in getting a value, using it
                                // and changing it all in one line
    stock[itemCount++] = itm2;
    stock[itemCount++] = itm3;

    return stock; // must use return statement to affect the array
}
```

}

order item class:

```
public class OrderItem {

private int itemCode = 1;
private String itemName;
private String itemSupplier;
private double itemCost;
private Department dept;

public OrderItem(String itemName, String itemSupplier, double itemCost, Department dept) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemSupplier = itemSupplier;
    this.itemCost = itemCost;
    this.dept = dept;
    
    

}

public String getDetails() {
    String res = "Item Name: "+getItemName()+", Supplier: "+getSupplier()+", Department: "+dept+", Cost: "+getitemCost();

    return res;

}

public int useNextCode() {

    this.itemCode = useNextCode();

    itemCode++;

    return itemCode;

}

public int getItemCode() {
    
    return this.itemCode;

}

public String getItemName() {
    
    return this.itemName;
}

public String getSupplier() {
    
    return this.itemSupplier;
    
}

public double getitemCost() {
    return this.itemCost;
}

public String toString() { 

    String res = "Item Code: "+getItemCode()+", Item Name: "+getItemName()+", Supplier: "+getSupplier()+", Department "+dept+" Cost: "+getitemCost();

    return res;


    
}
```

}

Comment: Show code of the `OrderItem` class

Comment: just added it @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value of `itemCode` - it have always the default value of `1`.

Add a parameter `int itemCode` to the constructor, add also a following line:

```
this.itemCode = itemCode
```

And then, modify `addThreeItems` in the following way:

```
public static OrderItem[] addThreeItems(OrderItem[] stock, int itemCount) { // Adds 3 predetermined items

    stock[itemCount] = new OrderItem(itemCount, "X Box Series X", "Microsoft", 449.99, Department.COMPUTING);
    itemCount++;
    stock[itemCount] = new OrderItem(itemCount, "Playstation 5 ", "Sony", 449.99, Department.COMPUTING);
    itemCount++;
    stock[itemCount] = new OrderItem(itemCount, "Oculus Quest 2", "Facebook", 299.00, Department.COMPUTING);
    itemCount++;

    return stock; // must use return statement to affect the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently initialising a new 'itemCode' integer every time you create a new instance of OrderItem.

If you want 'itemCode' to update, you will need to change the delcaration of 'itemCode' in OrderItem to:

```
private static int itemCode = 1;
```

What would be even better would be if you assigned this in the constructor:

```
private final int itemCode;
private static int nextCode = 1;
private String itemName;
private String itemSupplier;
private double itemCost;
private Department dept;

public OrderItem(String itemName, String itemSupplier, double itemCost, Department dept) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemSupplier = itemSupplier;
    this.itemCost = itemCost;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.itemCode = nextCode++;
    

}
```